# How (if at all) can I use Perl POD documentation in a shell script?

Tags: shell, perl-pod

I wonder: In Perl POD is recognized partially by the Perl parser, and there is the `__END__` keyword to stop Perl parsing.
If I want to write POD in a shell script (maybe at the end of the script), can that be done, and if so: How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dummy here document can be used in the shell to make it ignore the POD contents, while `perldoc` will be able to find it.
Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#... usual shell commands here ...
echo "Hello, world"
# POD starts here
: <<'__POD__'
=pod

=head1 NAME

The hello-world program...
Blabla..

=cut

__POD__
```

Doing a `sh podtest` runs the script.
Doing a `perldoc podtest` shows the doc.
Newer versions of `perldoc` (like 3.28) may require option `-F` to find the POD.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I'd also quote the heredoc to avoid any substitutions: `: << 'END_OF_POD'`

Comment: I tested it, but there is a problem: The documentation would end with `END_OF_POD`. Maybe show a short real example that 1) runs correctly in the shell, 2) passes `podchecker`, and 3) produces the correct output using `perldoc`.

Comment: You don't use podchecker and perldoc. It's a shell script which serves the same purpose. I didn't expect that you would use perldoc for generating code. However, in this case - how is  _peldoc_ behaving if you use `__END__` to terminate the _here_-string, instead of `END_OF_POD`?

Comment: @U.Windl : Added example.

Comment: OK, adding a `=cut` at the end does the trick. `perldoc` does not recognize `__END__` as special.

Comment: @U.Windl : Uh, my Perl days are already long time back. How about using `__DATA__` instead of `__END__`? The Perl parser is not supposed to touch thing in the __DATA__ area.

Comment: What I had meant to say was: `=cut` at the end does the trick (terminate POD processing), while `<<'__END__'` is not different from any other string. However with `=cut` that does not matter.

Comment: @user1934428 Unfortunately I found a problem today: While the answer works fine for perl-5.18.2 (Perldoc v3.19), it does not for perl-5.26.1 (Perldoc v3.28): When using the same input file I just get "*No documentation found for ...*" -- What could be the reason, and how can I fix it?

Comment: @U.Windl : I don't know what they changed in the perldoc command for the new version. My recommendation would be to check the release notes issued between 5.18 and 5.26, and if they don't mention such a change in behaviour, file a bug report to Perl itself.